# How to add a CLI file to the /CLI directory as part of a component install

Tags: component, manifest, cli

I have a component that needs a CLI file for use with cron. Is there a **proper** way to use the components manifest file to specify that the component includes a CLI file and that CLI file should be placed into the root CLI directory?

I know that I could easily do this via using the install stub in my components script.php file and just directly copy my file into the correct location, but I was wondering if there was a proper way to do this using the manifest file?

Answer (score 3):

Use `file` manifest to install files not belonging to any extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extension version="3.9" type="file" method="upgrade">
    <name>files_cli_example</name>
    <author>Example</author>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <creationDate>January 2019</creationDate>
    <description>FILES_CLI_EXAMPLE_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>
    <fileset>
        <files target="cli">
            <file>cli_example.php</file>
        </files>
    </fileset>
</extension>
```

Create a [Package](https://docs.joomla.org/Package) to install the component and custom files at once.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of the extension type 'file', that's very useful. The CLI file is very much part of my extension, so separating it into a separate extension within a package is less than optimal as Joomla doesn't yet have a package dependency mechanism. Admin's would be able to uninstall either the component or cli file, but leave the other on the system. At best, this would leave the system in inconsistent state and at worse it would start throwing errors. Ideally I was hoping for something like the <media> node, which allows a component to place files outside of its own directories.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I went with the script method I'd suggested in my question. Id did this because it meant that I could keep the cli file within the component, add it to the correct location when the component installed and remove it on uninstall.

I did this by adding a new cli folder to the root of my component, which contained the cli file I wanted to add `com_mycomponent_cron.php`.

Then in the script file, pointed to by the `<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>` in the components manifest xml, I added the following to both the install and update methods.

```
function install($parent)
{
    $source = \JPath::clean($parent->getParent()->getPath('source') . '/cli/com_mycomponent_cron.php');
    if ( !file_exists($source) ) {
        throw new RuntimeException('File cli/com_mycomponent_cron.php does not exist', 500);
    }
    $dest = \JPath::clean(JPATH_ROOT . '/cli/com_mycomponent_cron.php');

    //attempt to copy the file
    if ( !\JFile::copy($source,$dest) ) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Could not copy com_mycomponent_cron.php to cli folder.',500);

    }
}
```

and for the uninstall method I have this:

```
function uninstall($parent)
{
    $cli_script_path = \JPath::clean(JPATH_ROOT . '/cli/com_mycomponent_cron.php');
    if ( file_exists($cli_script_path) ) {
        \JFile::delete($cli_script_path);
    }
}
```

I've decided not to accept @Sharky's answer or mark my own as correct, as I don't think either are the 'correct' Joomla way to do things. Although I suspect that there probably isn't a 'correct' way.

Answer (score 1):

The current Joomla package manifest has the ability to block child uninstalls so only the full package can be uninstalled, not individual components. Use the following in your package manifest:

```
<blockChildUninstall>true</blockChildUninstall>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing.  Please tell us a bit about yourself and your Joomla background by editing your profile.